# How should I evaluation a candidate in a interview?

Tags: human-resources

Let me go straight to my problems. We currently work on a web project and planned to develop a mobile version someday. But, today my big boss came to my desk and ask me to do interview a candidate who has 2 years of experience in Flutter to prepare the mobile phase. It's pretty hard for me cause I don't have any experience working in that fields. My concern is " How should I evaluate him tomorrow ?"

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Hi Tea, welcome to PM.SE! Questions about interview are more on-topic on TheWorkplace SE (https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). "Interviewing" is at the moment the tag with most questions (https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interviewing). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Interviews are already a very weak employee selection method.  Biases interfere with our ability to objectively evaluate someone to predict future performance.  It is barely better than a coin toss.  You'll hear folks who disagree with that but that is because they are very likely unaware of the science behind it.

If you are unable to assess the skill set because you have no knowledge and experience with it, then you would not be the right person to do the interview.  You might be able to evaluate--notwithstanding the biases--the person's ability to "fit-in" the culture, or other non technical skills, but that would be it.  And, of course, your assessment would be heavily clouded by your biases.  I would suggest you finding someone who at least is aware of the technical skills to jump in.